# href attribute is required in combination with history react module

Tags: reactjs, eslint, href

I use the [history](https://github.com/remix-run/history) React module to manage the session history, and have links such as:

```
<a
    className="edit"
    onClick={() => {
        history.push(`/user/${this.props.match.params.id}/${i.slug}`);
    }}
>
    Edit User
</a>
```

This generates the following warning from ESLint:

```
The href attribute is required for an anchor to be keyboard accessible. Provide a valid, navigable address as the href value. If you cannot provide an href, but still need the element to resemble a link, use a button and change it with appropriate styles. Learn more: https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/HEAD/docs/rules/anchor-is-valid.md  jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid
```

**Is there a way to resolve this warning without turning the hyperlink into a button?**
(given the complexity of the CSS going on inside the repository, converting it to a button would be a lot of work.)

If I just add `href`, like below, then the ESLint warning is solved. But can the `history` module then still do its job properly?

```
<a
    className="edit"
    href={`/user/${this.props.match.params.id}/${i.slug}`}   //extra line
    onClick={() => {
        history.push(`/user/${this.props.match.params.id}/${i.slug}`);
    }}
>
    Edit User
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using `href` is necessary you can do something like : `href="javascript:void(0)"`